# Поправить скрипт вкладки

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт, при нажатии которого в меню, появляются вкладки, но мне нужно, что при нажатии на 3 пункт, переходило по ссылке

```
<ul class="js-page-content-switch">
                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
```

```
$('.js-page-content-switch').each(function() {
    const $switch = $(this);
    const $content = $('.js-page-content');
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const link = $(this).attr('href');

            $content.find('.page-content').each((index, el) => $(el).removeClass('is-active'));
            $content.find(link).addClass('is-active');

            $switch.find('li').each((index, el) => $(el).removeClass('current-menu-item'));
            $(this).parent().addClass('current-menu-item');
        });
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, добавить 3-й ссылке `data-ref="true"` (оно не имеет специального значения, `data-`атрибут можно назвать как угодно):

```
<ul class="js-page-content-switch">
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a data-ref="true" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

А при клике, прервать функцию, если у ссылки есть атрибут с таким значением:

```
$('.js-page-content-switch').each(function() {
  const $switch = $(this);
  const $content = $('.js-page-content');

  $(this).find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      if (this.dataset.ref === "true") return; // <---

      e.preventDefault();
      const link = $(this).attr('href');
      //...
```

Также, можно делать такую `if (this.href === "https://google.com") return;` проверку, не трогая HTML.

---

`const $content = $('.js-page-content');` — это потенциальная ошибка, элемент никак не привязан к `$switch`, а надо бы. Иначе при клике на любой `<a>` код будет выполняться для всех `js-page-content` на странице.

Comment: это да проблема. приходиться придумывать костыли